# React Native in crashlytics crashing

Tags: react-native

I have set up the `crashlytics` for error reporting using the snippet below. When testing the react-native app, the `crashlytics` seems to break.

```
await Promise.all([
    crashlytics().setUserId(user.uid),
    crashlytics().setAttribute('credits', String(user.credits)),
    crashlytics().setAttributes({
      role: 'admin',
      followers: '13',
      email: user.email,
      username: user.username,
    }),
  ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
<Button title="Test Crash" onPress={() => crashlytics().crash()} />
```